# Uniform phase array length and array beam -width

Tags: wireless

The larger the number of antennas (with spacing =lambda/2) in a uniform phase array, the narrower the beam-width. Is there an intuitive or mathematical explanation for that? How is the total length of the array or total delay related to the beam-width or main lobe width?

Comment: Per Fourier optics, the beam pattern in the far field is the Fourier transform of the array.  Since there is a Fourier transform relationship, making the array wider will give you a narrower beam.  If you find that intuitive will depend on how you feel about Fourier transforms.

Answer (score 1):

The far field emission pattern of an antenna is closely related to the spatial Fourier transform of the antenna shape.

And as you know, when we take the Fourier transform of some function, a function with a greater extent will generally have a narrower extent in the Fourier domain and vice versa.

So a spatially larger antenna can generally (if designed and excited properly---this is where the "phased" aspect of the phased array becomes critical) produce a narrower beam in the far field. This is true of both single-element and phased-array antennas. Indeed a major benefit of a phased array antenna is that it is possible to make the overall extent of the antenna very large without having to fill in all the intervening space with material, and thus achieve a narrow beam.